# Is it possible to isolate acceess to a bean used in a library in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Good day to you all.

I want to create a simple spring boot library for internal use. In such library I need to have a custom configured `RestTemplate` so, in config class

```
@Bean("libRestTemplate")
public RestTemplate libRestTemplate(){
   
   return buildItSomehow();
}
```

now I can easily use it in a scope of my lib using `@Qualifier("libRestTemplate")` whenever I need to. However, if a "host application" will try to aquire a `RestTemplate` instance, `libRestTemplate` will be a candidate for injection. This is something I need to avoid.

So is there a way to isolate such bean so it will be injectable only where required explicitly and will not be a candidato for "match-by-type" injection in other parts of application?